# A word that becomes a beauty - What am I?

Tags: riddle, anagram

> As I am, joy I should produce
>
> Switch my first and third letters and magic I can let loose
>
> If you put me first before all, I will be very large
>
> Remove my second letter and place my last in its place
>
> Then often I'll sit, a beauty in a case

What am I?

This has been through the [sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> game

*As I am, joy I should produce*

> games are fun and make people happy

*Switch my first and third letters and magic I can let loose*

> mage

*If you put me first before all, I will be very large*

> Move "me" to the front to get "mega", a prefix meaning large

*Remove my second letter and place my last in its place*
*Then often I'll sit, a beauty in a case*

> gem

Comment: I figured out the last line - added it in for you. (Also, +1!)

Comment: Yup, yup, yup.  You hit it in the nose.